# Unable to find hgrc file

Tags: mercurial, hgrc

I am trying to set up my username and password for mercurial. The answers to previous questions says to add the following lines in the .hgrc file

```
[ui]
username = MY_USER_NAME
password = MY_PASSWORD
```

However I am unable to find this file, I only see .hg file in my main directory.

Comment: oh okay found the answer, so you have to first create the .hgrc  

    vim .hg/.hgrc

and then 

    [ui]
    username = YOUR_NAME <YOUR_MAIL>

Answer (score 0):

On my windows machine I have a **mercurial.ini** file in c:\users\my_user_name

On my mac, I have a **.hgrc** file in my home directory.

Comment: I'm using a mac, and I only have a .hg folder in my home directory. I feel as I'm missing something.. so far what I did is use the command hg init to create the .hg directory